# UPDATED: Returning a pointer to an array from a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I know this is a similar question to previous questions but I couldn't find a suitable answer that I could follow.

I am trying to create an array of values in a function and then return a pointer to this array to be used in later functions and in the  main. I am having issues simply in understanding how to properly send and access the array. Following is a portion of my code (I have deleted irrelevant parts only)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std; 

double *PMS() {

  static double w[128];
  double dw = 0.05;
  int i; 

  for (i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
    w[i]  = dw + (2*i - 1) * (dw/2.0);
    cout << w[i] << endl;
    }

  cout << w[i] << endl;
  return w;
}

//======================================================================
void RandSea() { 
  double *omega;
  int i;

  omega = PMS();
 for (i = 0; i <=129;i++)
  cout << *omega << endl;
 }

int main() {
  data(values);
  Pierson_Moskowitz();
  RandSeaState();
}
```

The array is not correctly sending the values  `0x6021e0` from `cout<<omega<<endl;` in the RandSea function.

the value for omega is just zero.

Comment: What do you expect `cout << omega << endl;` to output, other than the address of the array defined here `static double w[129];` actually?

Comment: What is `M` ? Note also that in C/C++ index starts at `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Here is a very extensive explanation of pointers and different operators you can use on them: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: `cout << w[i] << endl;` is not in a loop and outputs only one value - might be another of your problems (apart from the ones already mentioned)

Comment: @Jarod42 : sorry I meant to delete M. It is left over from the rest of the code that I deleted that wasn't relevant in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things to note here:-

1) array indices start at 0 and ends at size-1.

2)   `cout << omega << endl;`

This would be printing the base address of the array.

You should use :-

```
omega = PMS();
for ( int i = 0; i < 129; i++ )   <<<<Here 129 should be the number of elements array has
{
   cout << *(omega + i) << endl;
}
```

3) You are returning the address of array to the caller. How would it get to know how many elements are there in an array.

"My second question is that I'm also having some trouble understanding the difference between the * and the & for pointers"

The & is known as "address of" operator. It used to get an address of an object. And '*' is "value at address of" operator in context of pointers.

Comment: First of all, yes I understand that array indices start at size 1 and end at size-1.. Originally when I wasn't using pointers, I just sent the arrays to size 200... Should I only have set them the size that is being counted and not bigger to be safe? The size of the array is 128 elements.

Comment: If i'me  trying to print out the the values int he array that were calculated in the PMS function, what should I use to print the value and not the address? Would I need to print *omega?

Comment: Thank you, that does work. I don't really understand why though! What is the difference between *(omega+i) and *omega? (Please see updated question where I included the for loop for omega

Comment: When you write array name it means you are referring to base address of array. And then you write omega+1, that means address of next element. So ,*(omega+1) will give you value at that address.You could refer some book on pointer and arrays to get the details.

Comment: Ok so what if I wanted to use the value of omega again? do I  need to set another variable equal to *(omega+i) in the loop? For instance, in the function, I want to use the values calculated for omega to calculate another variable for each omega value... this i don't really understand (don't worry, I have loads of books on pointers!! I find that the explanations are often difficult to follow if you're inexperienced in programming)